# R: strange behavior in data.table when attempting to operate on a column using another data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to operate on a data.table column using a different data.table, and assign the result to a new column in the first data.table. But I keep having this issue:

```
Warning messages:
1: In from:(from + len) :
  numerical expression has 10 elements: only the first used
```

Here is the data:

```
tstamps = c(1504306173, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1504393006, NA, NA, 1504459211, NA)
set.seed(0.1)
dt1 = data.table(utc_tstamp = sample(rep(tstamps, 100), 100))
dt2 = data.table(from = sample((1:90), 10), len = sample(1:10, 10))

> dt2
    from len
 1:   55   6
 2:   59   9
 3:   32  10
 4:   24   3
 5:   86   7
 6:   54   1
 7:   18   5
 8:   11   8
 9:   40   4
10:   75   2
```

I'm trying to count the number of `NA`'s in `dt1[from:(from+len), ]` and assign the result to a new column, count, in `dt2`.

What I currently have for that is this

```
dt2[, count := dt1[from:(from+len), ][is.na(utc_tstamp), .N]]
```

but this is only using `dt2[1,]$from` and `dt2[1,]$len`, all the counts are just the number of `NA`'s in `dt1[dt2[1,]$from:(dt2[1,]$from + dt2[1,]$len), ]`, and I receive the following warning

```
Warning messages:
1: In from:(from + len) :
  numerical expression has 10 elements: only the first used
2: In from:(from + len) :
  numerical expression has 10 elements: only the first used
```

and the result is this:

```
> dt2
    from len count
 1:   55   6     5
 2:   59   9     5
 3:   32  10     5
 4:   24   3     5
 5:   86   7     5
 6:   54   1     5
 7:   18   5     5
 8:   11   8     5
 9:   40   4     5
10:   75   2     5
```

while it should be this:

```
> dt2
    from len count
 1:   55   6     5
 2:   59   9     5
 3:   32  10     8
 4:   24   3     3
 5:   86   7     5
 6:   54   1     2
 7:   18   5     4
 8:   11   8     5
 9:   40   4     4
10:   75   2     2
```

I'd appreciate it if someone explains why this is happening and how can I get what I want.

Comment: @akrun I added set.seed and the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the description, we get the sequence between the 'from' and 'from' added with 'len', based on this position index get the corresponding elements of 'utc_stamp' column from 'dt1', convert it to logical (`is.na(`), and get the `sum` i.e. sum of TRUE elements or the number of `NA` elements.  Assign (`:=`) it to create a new column 'count' in 'df2'

```
dt2[, count := unlist(Map(function(x, y) 
              sum(is.na(dt1$utc_tstamp[x:y])),  from , from + len))]
dt2
#    from len count
# 1:   55   6     5
# 2:   59   9     5
# 3:   32  10     8
# 4:   24   3     3
# 5:   86   7     5
# 6:   54   1     2
# 7:   18   5     4
# 8:   11   8     5
# 9:   40   4     4
#10:   75   2     2
```

---

Or another option is to group by sequence of rows and then do the the sequence (`:`) based on 'from', 'len' columns to subset the column values from 'dt1' and get the `sum` of logical `vector`

```
dt2[, count := sum(is.na(dt1$utc_tstamp[from:(from + len)])), by = 1:nrow(dt2)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Or define the joining variables explicitly and use a non-equi join:

```
dt2[, to := from+len]
dt1[, r := .I]

dt2[, ct := dt1[is.na(utc_tstamp)][dt2, on=.(r >= from, r <= to), .N, by=.EACHI]$N]
```